# Change html,js,css files into Single file component

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am currently trying to save user data into local storage. It is working fine in the html,js files. When I use the code in a single file component the data is not storing into local storage. When I check local storage it says value 'SILENT'.

```
<template>
<div id ="register">
<form id ="details" method="POST" onsubmit="return false"> >
<span>

Name: <input v-model='name' type='name'>
Email: <input v-model="email" type="email">
Password: <input v-model="password" type="password">
<button type="submit">Register </button> 
</span>
</form>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
name: 'registerdetails',
data: function(){
return
name:'',
email:'',
password:'',
```

},

```
methods: {
  onsubmit: function() {
  console.log("submitting..");
  // check any other emails to see if it exists already

  var userdetails = []; 
  var newEmail = this.email;
  if (localStorage.getItem("userdetails")) {
    userdetails= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userdetails"));
  }
  if (userdetails) {
    if (
      userdetails.some(function(userdetails) {
        return userdetails.email === newEmail;
      })
    ) {
      alert("Email exists!"); 
      return;
}

 userdetails.push({ email: newEmail, password: this.password }); //add the new email and password to the local storage
    localStorage.setItem("userdetails", JSON.stringify(userdetails));


  } else {
    userdetails = [{ email: newEmail, password: this.password }]; 
    localStorage.setItem("userdetails", JSON.stringify(userdetails));
  }
},
 }
 }
```

Comment: The error message is telling you not to change props, which happens in your inputs.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Do I not use props then? Slightly confused.

Comment: Vue forces a good practice for parent/child communication which goes like:  Pass data down via props, `$emit` data up via events.  It might seem pointless at first but it's an important practice for keeping code maintainable.  If children can mutate parent data, it can quickly become very difficult to debug and manage.  A global store like `Vuex` solves this problem as well, often in an even better way.(But not always-- it depends on the purpose of the components.)

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's multiple problems, it looks like you've already sorted your props problem.

When checking if an email already exists, it would atleast be clearer if the iteration variable was called something else other than userdetails i.e. userdetail

```
 userdetails.some(function(userdetail) {
    return userdetail.email === newEmail;
 })
```

You're also initializing userdetails as a string but then do a push later on, which doesn't exist on a string.

```
var userdetails = [];
```

EDIT: I updated my answer with a fiddle, it doesn't work in the fiddle environment for security reasons with localStorage but I copied it into a .html file and it seemed to work.

```js
new Vue ({
  el: '#register',
  data: function() {
    return {
      name: '',
      email: '',
      password: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onsubmit: function() {
      let userDetails = [];
      let localUserDetails = localStorage.getItem("userDetails");
      
      if(localUserDetails)
      userDetails = JSON.parse(localUserDetails);
      
        if (userDetails && userDetails.some(x => x.email === this.email)) 
        {
          alert("Email exists!");
          return;
        }

        let newUserDetails = {
          email: this.email,
          password: this.password
        };
        
        userDetails.push(newUserDetails); 
        localStorage.setItem("userDetails", JSON.stringify(userDetails));
      }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="register">
  <form id="details" method="POST" @submit.prevent="onsubmit">
    <div>
      Name: <input v-model="name" type="name" />
    </div>
    <div>
      Email: <input v-model="email" type="email" />
    </div>
    <div>
      Password: <input v-model="password" type="password" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Register</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I understand the first two parts but slightly confused about the push.

Comment: Your code does this: var userdetails = ""; which sets a variable called userdetails to an empty string. If the localStorage item doesn't exist then it does: userdetails.push({ email: newEmail, password: this.password }); which you can't do, you'll get an error - push is not a function

Comment: Thank you for explaining that, I really appreciate it, but this code worked when I had a separate file e.g. html, js,css . But when I changed it to single file component it's not working. Is there a specific reason for that.

Comment: I can't think of a reason if the code is the same, so maybe something was changed in   the process

Comment: I changed it to an array but it's not doing anything. No error messages either.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This [article](https://michaelnthiessen.com/avoid-mutating-prop-directly/) should explain it for you. Do these fields need to be properties (e.g. getting pass from the parent component)? If not, you should just make them as data:

```
 data: function() {
        return {
            name: '',
            email: '',
            password: '',
        }
    },
```

Comment: The data is not getting stored into the local storage.